# Doxygen 1.8.8 onwards: is html supported for INPUT files

Tags: html, doxygen

I want to generate documentation in Doxygen using .html files as INPUT (i.e in the INPUT tag).
This worked for all my previous versions of Doxygen (i.e. up to 1.8.7).
However, I notice that when I do this using 1.8.8 and above (I actually noticed it first on 1.8.10), the html files are not used to generate any documentation. If I change these html files to .dox, then the documentation is indeed generated correctly.
Is html still a valid extension format for Doxygen post 1.8.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to fix this problem by adding the following in the doxygen config file:

EXTENSION_MAPPING html=C

This is based on the information contained in the Doxygen manual FAQ page.